# InvalidOperationException was unhandled Not allowed to change the 'ConnectionString' property. On C#

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, ado.net, oledbconnection

I have this kind of error although the syntax is correct and I encounter an InvalidOperationExeption.
[image: Screenshot Sample]

[image: On my dbs.cs class]

On my konek function on class dbs

```
public String konek()
{
            connectionString = "Provider=" + OleDBProvider + ";Data Source=" + OleDBDataSource + ";JET OLEDB:Database Password=" + OleDBPassword + ";Persist Security Info=" + PersistSecurityInfo + "";
            return connectionString;
}
```

Comment: it's better to paste your code and it's exception message on your question content instead of image.

Answer (score 1):

You have to **create new OleDbConnection object** instead of reusing existing one.

```
OleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(db.konek());
```

Also, it is not a good practice to keep connection open for long time.
So, close the connection as soon as your operation is complete.

I believe in your case, if you have already created the `OleDbConnection` object with same `ConnectionString` then no need to reassign same connection string again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You not allowed to modify connection string property. try template bellow:

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(db.konek()))
{
   try
   {
       connection.Open();
       ....
       ....
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       ....
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be that the `con` object is already `Open` causing it to be read-only. One way of solving this is to create another instance for your `Connection` object.

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection())
{
    con.ConnectionString = db.konek();
}
```

*make scope as little as possible.*

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says, your "con" already has the connection open.

You may wish to re-use the existing connection or replace only if the connection is not open:

```
if(con.State!=ConnectionState.Open)
{
con.ConnectionString = db.Konek();
}
```

But modifying a connection string while it already has a value and is open, shows there is some flaw in your code logic.